# Simulate WiFi in mother's home to preprogram devices being sent

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to set up WiFi devices for my mother who lives in another state.

If I name my router the same as hers with the same password and set up my devices on it, will they connect at her home without any changes?

Plug and play is what I'm aiming for. Google Nest hub is what I'm working on now for slideshows only.

My concern is that when setting up devices there's more going on behind the scenes that make the name and password superficial.

Comment: In Windows 10 I've been able to do this by going to Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi > Manage known networks > Add a new network

You can usually figure out the default security protocol by looking up their router's manual/specs etc online -- use that for the "Security type" dropdown selection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work.

I have been using this method when replacing my router with a
newer model. It just works.

You need to ensure that both routers use the same SSID and password,
and broadcasting on the same band. If the routers
have the same characteristics, all devices will automatically
connect. This includes computers, phones, and even house
appliances.

Comment: You only need the same SSID and password operating on the same band. Channel can vary and you can use different routers too.